# jquery autocomplete shows weird message while retrieving data from local storage

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, local-storage, jquery-ui-autocomplete

May be I am not able to search this one properly on net. currently problem I am facing is I am using jquery auto complete with localStorage means if user's local storage has data use from that otherwise it'll make AJAX call and send data to autocomplete now situation is like if I am getting through AJAX autocomplete works fine but if it's from local storage it's showing error like

```
jquery-1.11.0.js:9666 GET http://localhost:8080/organizationSource/[%…value%22:%%22,%%22:%225625%22%7D]?term=ll&_=149631722767 400
```

my code fro that is like

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds")!==undefined && localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds")!==null){
 var data=localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds");
 callAutocomplete(data);
}
else{ 
 $.ajax({
  url:"/organizationSourceMapping/loadOrgs.htm",
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data){
   localStorage.setItem("orgListandIds",data);
   callAutocomplete(data)
  }
 })
}
}
function callAutocomplete(data){
 $("#searchByText").autocomplete({
  maxShowItems:5,
  minLength:2,
  autoFocus: true,
  source:data,
  select:function(event,ui){
 
   idValue=ui.item.idValue;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried to store data in localStorge using JSON.stringify but that also dint work

Comment: I'm voting to delete this message because user didn't even try to format message as it should!

Comment: I pasted the same message what I received from chrome. what formation u need?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I got suggestion that storage is returning JSON object and I need to parse before sending to auto complete. so I made the change like this

```js
if(localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds")!==undefined && localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds")!==null){
 var data=localStorage.getItem("orgListandIds");
 callAutocomplete(JSON.parse(data));
}
else{ 
 $.ajax({
  url:"/organizationSourceMapping/loadOrgs.htm",
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data){
   localStorage.setItem("orgListandIds",JSON.stringify(data));
   callAutocomplete(data)
  }
 })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```